# Как выровнять input в css?

Tags: html, css

Как поставить лейбл по центру?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.choose-master {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #DFDFDF;
    border-radius: 4px;
    padding: 20px 20px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex-wrap: wrap;

    &__item {
        width: 200px;
        margin-bottom: 5px;
        vertical-align: center;
    }

    &__text {
        font-family: $main-font-family;
        font-style: normal;
        font-weight: normal;
        font-size: 1rem;
        line-height: 1.25rem;
        color: #222;
        cursor: pointer;
        // padding-bottom: 5px;
    }


    &__label {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 18px;
        height: 18px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        border: 2px solid #222222;
        cursor: pointer;
        position: relative;
        // margin-top: 10px;

        &::before {
            content: "";
            width: 10px;
            height: 10px;
            display: none;
            background-color: #FF7A00;
            border-radius: 50%;
            position: absolute;
            top: 50%;
            left: 50%;
            transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
        }

    }

    &__radio {
        display: none;

        &:checked + .choose-master__label::before {
           display: block; 
        }
    }
}
```

```html
 <div class="choose-master">
                <!-- <label for="name" class="appointment-form__label">Choose master:</label> -->
                <div class="choose-master__item">
                    <input type="radio" class="choose-master__radio" name="choose-master__item" id="master-1" value="1">
                    <label for="master-1" class="choose-master__label"></label>
                    <label for="master-1" class="choose-master__text">Choose something</label>
                </div>
                <div class="choose-master__item">
                    <input type="radio" class="choose-master__radio" name="choose-master__item" id="master-2" value="2">
                    <label for="master-2" class="choose-master__label"></label>
                    <label for="master-2" class="choose-master__text">Choose something</label>
                </div>
                <div class="choose-master__item">
                    <input type="radio" class="choose-master__radio" name="choose-master__item" id="master-3" value="3">
                    <label for="master-3" class="choose-master__label"></label>
                    <label for="master-3" class="choose-master__text">Choose something</label>
                </div>
                <div class="choose-master__item">
                    <input type="radio" class="choose-master__radio" name="choose-master__item" id="master-4" value="4">
                    <label for="master-4" class="choose-master__label"></label>
                    <label for="master-4" class="choose-master__text">Choose something</label>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Выровнять по центру можешь используя flexbox:

```
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
```

Answer (score 0):

Как-то так

```
   margin:0px auto;
    padding:0px;
```